# best way to add multi language to static HTML Page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I purchase a static HTML, CSS, JavaScript(jQuery) landing page template and I need to add language to it, it has some animations in text for example

```html
 <h2 class="large-title-bold">
   <span
   class="slider-title-fill slider-tr-delay01"
   data-text="Enjoy"
   >Enjoy</span
   ><br />
   <span
   class="slider-title-fill slider-tr-delay02"
   data-text="the Difference &"
   >the Difference &</span
   ><br />
   <span
   class="slider-title-fill slider-tr-delay03"
   data-text="the Luxury!"
   >the Luxury!</span
   >
   </h2>
```

it's a title which I need to have both English and Turkish lang, what is the best way that I can achieve this?

Comment: If you don't care about SEO you can use a client library such as https://github.com/wikimedia/jquery.i18n. If you do, it's better to do it on the server or create 2 different static pages.

Comment: You can store sentences of each languages in arrays and add one more data attribute with lang. So you can use button to change language with javascript.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways of how to do this. A very simple way is to do it over HTML, CSS and JavaScript (no backend programming language needed).

**HTML**

You will need to work with `lang` attribute for every single text.

```html
<h2 class="large-title-bold">
  <span class="slider-title-fill slider-tr-delay01" data-text="Enjoy">
    <span lang="en">Enjoy</span>
    <span lang="fr">Profitez</span>
  </span><br />
  <span class="slider-title-fill slider-tr-delay02" data-text="the Difference &">
    <span lang="en">the Difference &</span>
    <span lang="fr">la différence &</span>
  </span><br />
  <span class="slider-title-fill slider-tr-delay03" data-text="the Luxury!">
    <span lang="en">the Luxury!</span>
    <span lang="fr">le luxe!</span>
  </span>
</h2>
```

**CSS**

Hide all elements with `lang` attributes.

```css
span[lang=en], span[lang=fr] {
  display: none
}
```

**JavaScript**

Display only the elements with the active language.

```js
const url = new URL(window.location.href);
const lang = url.searchParams.get('lang');

if (lang) {
    elements = document.querySelectorAll(`span[lang=${lang}]`);
  for (let element of elements) {
    element.style.display = 'inherit';
  }
}
```

Your URL should be either *example.com?lang=en* or *example.com?lang=fr*